# I need to make an typing tutor, where to start?

Tags: java, typing

I'm making a typing tutor in java (netbeans).
Now i have made an keyboard in gui .

A simple example of how I want it: the <kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>A</kbd> are buttons and in the text field you can type.

Now there are some lessons to do
Lesson 1: abb ab abb (example)

So the A button needs to be red then you press <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd> becomes red you press <kbd>B</kbd>.

How can I import this lessons into my application ? (notepad)
And how can I make the <kbd>A</kbd> becomes red when it needs to be?

I do not have some codes yet because I don't know where to start.

Comment: Why not simply use an existing tool like http://www.tipp10.com/en/

Comment: i need to make it myself for a project

Answer (score 2):

Make a class `Lesson` with a collection of characters.

You can make for each `Lesson` a file.
Read the files into `Lesson` objects and then go over the collection to the next char when the user has pressed the right button.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what this question is about. It seems you want help to program the tutor and learning Java in the go. Stackoverflow is a Q&A-Platform, you should ask every concrete problem in a single question.

Anyways, I can see two questions packaged in the post:

### 1. How can I read a textfile in my program?

At least that is what I understand with 'importing the lesson'. Use a [`BufferedReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html). With [`readLine()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) you can read one line after the other into a `String`.

### 2. How to color something I painted red?

I don't know how you painted the keyboard. But most likely you used the [`Graphics`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html)-object in the `paint()`-method. `Graphics` has a [`setColor()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setColor%28java.awt.Color%29)-method, so you can type something like this: `setColor(Color.RED);` before painting the element.

Answer (score 1):

I would think you would do one of two options:

1. Add a listener for each key press (say an `InputMethodListener`) to the text field. In the listener, update the GUI to change the appropriate key's color.

[JTextComponent.addImputMetherListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#addInputMethodListener%28java.awt.event.InputMethodListener%29)

1. Add a `Keymap` where for each key you have an `Action` that will change the background color of the appropriate section of the GUI.

[JTextComponent.setKeymap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setKeymap%28javax.swing.text.Keymap%29)

Comment: i have lessons in notepad file so lesson 1 is: abb 
first a needs to be red and then b twice
so how can i import this in

Comment: Read the file. Take a look at apache commons FileUtils.

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString(java.io.File)